# How to typeset aligned equations with a curly brace to the left and subnumbering

Tags: equations, numbering, typography, subequations

I want to typeset multiple equations that are

- aligned by the '=' sign
- are combined by a curly brace to the left
- have 'subnumbering'.

They should look like

{ a = b  (1.1)a

{ c = d  (1.1)b

{ e = f  (1.1)c

where the '{'s represent one big curly brace to the left. I want to be able to refer to a specific subequation such as '(1.1)a', as well as to all of them by '(1.1)'.

I was able to construct equations with a curly brace, but they only have a common number, such as '(1.1)'. How to add the 'subnumbering'?

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \left\{
    \begin{array}{rcll}
        a & = & b \\
        c & = & d \\
        e & = & f
    \end{array}
    \right.
    \label{eq:test}
\end{equation}
See equation \ref{eq:test}.
\end{document}
```

(Excuse me if this question does already exist, but so far I have not found an answer to this specific question.)

Comment: please, provide mwe

Comment: for english-only speakers, "accolade" in this sense is a curly brace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mathtools,cases}

\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}\label{eq:test}
\begin{numcases}{}
    a = b &     \label{eq:1a}\\
    c = d &     \label{eq:1b}\\
    e = f &     \label{eq:1c}     
\end{numcases}
See \eqref{eq:test} and more precisely \eqref{eq:1a}, \eqref{eq:1b} and \eqref{eq:1c}.
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

addendum.
your second request can be easy fulfilled with `empheq` package or with following changes of above mwe:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mathtools,cases}

\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}\label{eq:test}
\begin{numcases}{}
   &\llap{aaa} = b       \label{eq:1a}\\
   &\llap{c} = d      \label{eq:1b}\\
   &\llap{e} = f       \label{eq:1c}
\end{numcases}
See \ref{eq:test} and more precisely \ref{eq:1a}, \ref{eq:1b} and \ref{eq:1c}.
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And you can add labels to each line of the `numcases`, as well as to a group of `numcases`?

Comment: @Karlo, see modified answer.

Comment: And how to align by '='?

Comment: with `numcases` is not so simply as with `empheq`, but see addendum to my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Another solution, with the `empheq` environment (needless to load `amsmath`: it loads `mathtools`, which  loads it). It works with `cleverref`, and you can refer the equation as a whole, or the individual subsequations:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
    \begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
        a & = b[![enter image description here][1]][1] \\
        c & = d\label{sseqb} \\
        e & = f
    \end{empheq}
    \label{eq:test}
\end{subequations}
See \cref{eq:test} and more precisely \cref{sseqb}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

here is your answer but change the code slightly and put curly bracket in front of equations.

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}


\begin{subequations}\label{first:main}

First some separate equations
\begin{equation}
a & = & b \label{first:1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
c & = & d \label{first:2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
e & = & f \label{first:3}
\end{equation}
\end{subequations}


\end{document}
```